# Что работает быстрее? exit или else

Tags: php, производительность, логика

Вдруг стало интересно - есть ли различия в скорости выполнения скрипта php:

```
if(1!=1){ echo "Ошибка"; exit; }

/* дальше много - много кода */
```

или

```
if(1==1)
{
    /* много - много кода */
}
else
{
    echo "Ошибка";
}
```

Comment: 1. Если не знаете, что будет быстрее, возьмите и померяйте. 2. Не занимайтесь преждевременной оптимизацией. 3. Это не то место в коде, которое надо оптимизировать.

Comment: @Athari, человеку *интересно* стало, понимаете? Он пытается вникнуть в суть, подняться выше среднего серенького уровня. А Вы ему...  (да и ответы-советы как от человека, который ответа не знает, но что-то сказать хочет). (а плюс к этому еще и "минусуют" нещадно новичка, нехорошо).

Comment: @avp, *интерересно* - это что-то менее... неизмеримое :)

Comment: @avp Это отвратительный вопрос, который приводит к написанию отвратительных ответов. Лучше новичку сразу понять, что он занимается глупостями, чем вдаваться в детальные разъяснения вокруг изначально неправильного вопроса. / Мой первый комментарий — самый правильный ответ в данной ситуации. А вот попытки устроить бенчмарки — куда в меньшей степени.

Comment: @Athari, о бенчмаркинге я (неявно) написал в своем ответе (измерять не получится). / Жаль, что старожилы SO (5 лет стажа) придерживаются подобных взгядов на "правильность" вопросов и тому, чем программист должен заниматься. / В принципе, моя позиция по поводу хороший-плохой **вопрос** -- не нравится - пройди мимо (кроме, ну, совершенно экстремальной тупости вопроса (IMHO тут не тот случай)).

Comment: @avp, @ Athari, Девочки, не ссорьтесь, вы обе красивые. И обе правы... с какой-то стороны. С первой - это плохой вопрос и сразу надо дать понять чтобы автор не страдал фигнёй, всем (и автору) будет лучше. С другой - понимание как работает интерпретатор, его хинты и особенности - это прекрасно, есть шанс вырасти над собой и прочими :)

Comment: я не знаю, как там со скоростью. но второй вариант ужасен. и ужасным его делает именно комментарий `/* много-много кода */`. старайтесь избегать вложения больших участков кода в операции ветвления, это ухудшает читабельность кода.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если нельзя измерить, зачит надо просто думать.

Если код функции перед выполнением сначала читается целиком и компилируется в некую форму для интерпретатора, то разницы во времени исполнения не будет.

А если интерпретировать код "в лоб"  т.е. сразу, по мере  его чтения, то первая форма

```
if (condition) {... exit;}
```

без сомнения будет работать быстрее (если условие в if == true).

Т.о. вопрос сводится к -- *"Как работает интерпретатор PHP?"*

--

Моя догадка -- разницы во времени выполнения не будет.

--

Еще одно замечание -- не стоит делать измерения, когда в if константное выражение.

**Update**

Вижу в комментариях непонимание текста ответа.

В резюме я написал -- "Моя догадка -- разницы во времени выполнения не будет."

Это означает, что какая-то предварительная компиляция тела функции проводится, по крайней мере весь ее текст будет прочитан до исполнения, т.е. в реальности код не исполняется во время чтения.

Для подтверждения -- небольшой примерчик

```
avp@avp-xub11:hashcode$ cat t.php
<?php
if(1!=1)
{
   echo "1\n"
   echo Ошибка1;
}
else
{
   echo "2\n";
   echo Ошибка2;
}
?>
avp@avp-xub11:hashcode$ php <t.php 
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO), expecting ',' or ';' in - on line 5
avp@avp-xub11:hashcode$
```

Как видите -- Parse error в блоке, который не исполняется. А вот реакцию на ошибку `echo Ошибка2;` мы увидим, если исправим первую (отсутствует `;`)

```
avp@avp-xub11:hashcode$ php <t.php 
2
PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant Ошибка2 - assumed 'Ошибка2' in - on line 10
Ошибка2avp@avp-xub11:hashcode$
```

Мне кажется, что теперь все достаточно очевидно.

Comment: Насколько я знаю, PHP юзает компиляцию на лету, так что с построчным выполнением лёгкий облом.

Comment: @TheDoctor Всё хуже: зависит от версии, настройки и т.п.

Comment: @Athari, Есть такое, лень было расписывать, да и я не знаю точно что у пыха под юбкой, т.е. капотом.

Comment: Добавил кое-какие дополнительные разъяснения.

Answer (score 1):

А ничего что это вообще-то разные конструкции и сравнивать их нельзя?

Comment: А ничего, что итог выполнения кода одинаков, но скорость теоретически может быть разной? Значить сравнить можно, и нужно. В сущности, интересует будет ли php вообще смотреть то, что находится после exit...

Comment: @Василий, Чувак, это конструкции языка, а не функции (да, `exit` - конструкция, [пруф](https://php.net/manual/ru/function.exit.php)), их нельзя измерить (возможно, конечно, всё, но там надо разбирать ядро пыха, оно кому надо?). Пых смотреть за `exit` в любом случае будет - собирать классы, функции, константы и пр. А вот выполнять не будет.

Comment: первый достойный ответ! В первом случае php отрубится сразу, во втором будет искать окончания if для перехода к выполнению else, так ли это?

Comment: @Василий, Всегда пожалуйста :)

Comment: Вот и вопрос, что он сделает быстрее, отрубится сразу, или отрубится по выполнению всего скрипта

Comment: @Василий, Если в одной секции `if` ВЕСЬ код, а в другой (`else`) только `print 'Йа здох!';`, то разницы не будет.  
Если же не весь код в условии, то... как я сказал - это разные конструкции, сравнивать глупо.

Answer (score 0):

На первой же ссылке в гугле:

```
$start = microtime(true);
// ВАШ СКРИПТ
$time = microtime(true) - $start;
printf('Скрипт выполнялся %.4F сек.', $time);
```

Comment: Я вас опечалю: для бенчмарка `if` разрешения `microtime` не хватит. (Или я окончательно разочаруюсь в PHP.)

Comment: @Athari, Ну можно попробовать сделать стопицот циклов на `if` :)

Comment: Ну факт основного вопроса 
- "есть ли различия в скорости выполнения скрипта php"
отразил суть способа проверки, а там уж пусть включают мозг.
Во всяком случае если не хватит как выразились "бенчмарка", то увидят, что выполнение происходит слишком быстро, по показателям.

Comment: @TheDoctor Замечательно. А как сделать "стопицот" вызовов `exit`?

Comment: @Athari именно поэтому он выше и ответил, что сравнивать их ни в коем случае нельзя

Comment: @Athari, Возможно, если раскрутить ядро, переписать функцию `exit` с минимальными потерями, то... Нельзя, короче, сам вопрос глуп, ибо это конструкции, а не функции.

Comment: Скрипт - есть скрипт. На его считывание и преобразование в машинный код тратится время в любом случае независимо от конструкции. Единственно что как сказали - может не хватит простых существующих показателей для измерения этого времени. А научный подход тут явно не нужен.

Comment: @IvanZakirov, подход именно научный. Кода очень много, и хочется в будущем (прошлые проекты, конечно, трогать уже смысла нет) оформлять его оптимально...

Comment: Если научный то подойдите с точки зрения логики.
1) чем проще система, тем она надежнее
2) чем интуитивно понятнее структура кода, тем легче обслуживать (2й вариант больше подходит)
Ну а насчет времени выполнения этих конструкций, то они скорее всего будут одинаковы.

Comment: Может проще отрубить скрипт сразу, чем потом искать концы? если кода действительно много...

Comment: PHP, конструкцию кода забивает в память, и он не будет как первоклассник считывать весь ваш код построчно, пока не дойдет до ELSE. 
Соответственно команды ELSE - > ECHO или ECHO -> EXIT серверу не составит труда выполнить и скорость будет та же.

Comment: Поддержу @Athari, хотите сравнить производительность - лезте в опкод и считайте инструкции.